# Convert RedirectMatch to mod_rewrite cond/rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to convert two RedirectMatch rules to use mod_rewrite.

Here are the conditions:

```
RedirectMatch ^/rw/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/(.+) http://www.example.com/rw/$1 
RedirectMatch ^/rw/category/(.+) http://www.example.com/rw/$2
```

What would be the RewriteCond/RewriteRule statements to duplicate these rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^rw/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/(.+) http://www.example.com/rw/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^rw/category/(.+) http://www.example.com/rw/$2 [L,R]
```